# Displaying partial results when with will_paginate and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate for the first time. My initial implementation is working great. Something like:

```
@products = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

In the Product controller, this produces what I was expecting, and I can flip through product listings fine. What I'm trying to do now is show only products that contain the word "glass", and can't figure out how to get it done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `where` clause like this (assuming `@product.name` should contain "glass"):

```
@products = Product.where('name LIKE ?', '%glass%').paginate(...)
```

Don't forget the `paginate` arguments, which I removed for clarity.

Comment: This worked. I had tried something similar, but I was putting the %% around LIKE, not the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search word "glass" only from **one particular column** you can use it as,

```
 Product.where("'column_name' like ?","% glass %").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

And if you want to search it from whole record then you can use fulltext search.
check out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack?view=asciicast
and https://github.com/ernie/ransack

Gem **Ransack** provides full-text search.